# Android App build fail because of firebase-storage:11.0.2 dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dependencies, firebase-storage

I am trying to get some files url's from my firebase storage and to do so you must add the dependency:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
```

to your app in the app level gradle file. I did this, but now I receive the error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

I've looked the problem up online and the only solution I have found is that I need to add:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the bottom of my app level gradle file, which I already did awhile ago. I cannot seem to figure out what is causing this error.

app level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lonelygamer.dmc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your app module build.gradle.  The versions of all Firebase and Google Play Services dependencies must be identical.

Comment: @BobSnyder there ya go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versions of all Firebase and Google Play Services dependencies must be identical. Also recommend using the latest version of the Support Library: 25.4.0.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' // RECOMMENDED CHANGE
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2' // CHANGED
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2' // CHANGED
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your SDK then update the build gradle file with new APIs and google services at.... then sync the gradle